# Select elements by class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, templates

I have a button declared like this in a template

```
  <a class="comment-btn delete-comment">Delete</a>
```

I want to add an event listener for all the buttons that have the class `delete-comment`.
How can I do this in jQuery?

I tried somethign like this:

```
events:{
"click #delete-comment": "deleteComment"
{
```

but id doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please read some jquery introduction.

Comment: Use . before the classname and # before the id. This is the protocol.

Comment: $(".delete-comment").click(function () { })

Comment: Where do you have this `events : { ... }` declaration? Also as mentioned, you should probably read a jQuery introduction: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery and have a look at the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.delete-comment').on('eventName', function(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty straight forward:

```
$('.delete-comment').on('eventName', function(){
//your code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use...

```
    $(".delete-comment").click(function(){
      // Do some thing ...

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.delete-comment').click(function(){//your code});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('.delete-comment').click(function(){
       //YOUR CODE HERE  
    });
```

Comment: Creating a new event object here would over-complicate and over-engineer what the OP needs to do.